# Difference between "axes" and "axis" in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm confused about what the different between `axes` and `axis` is in matplotlib. Could someone please explain in an easy-to-understand way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Axis is the axis of the plot, the thing that gets ticks and tick labels. The axes is the area your plot appears in.

Comment: Is one supposed to get less confused or more confused with this? You say "the **axis** of the plot, the **thing** that ..."  as if there's a single axis, a single "thing"!!

Answer (score 119):

This figure from the documentation will answer your question:

[image]

You can find this image [here](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/faq/usage_faq.html#parts-of-a-figure) (in the Matplotlib 1.x docs); it's actually been replaced in the Matplotlib 2.x docs.

Comment: There is an equivalent image in current documentation, which many other concepts explained: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think that the old figure is more on point for the relevant question here.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I decided to provide the new link just in case the old one stops working. But the old figure is **much better** to ilustrate the axes/axis difference.

Answer (score 15):

in the context of matplotlib,

axes is not the plural form of axis, it actually denotes the plotting area, including all axis.

Comment: This was a horrible design decision.

Comment: I also feel it confusing, especially axes is just plural form of axis in English.

Comment: ..mother of god..