# What is the difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm kind of confused what is going at the backend when I draw plots in matplotlib, tbh, I'm not clear with the hierarchy of plot, axes and figure. I read the documentation and it was helpful but I'm still confused...

The below code draws the same plot in three different ways -

```
#creating the arrays for testing
x = np.arange(1, 100)
y = np.sqrt(x)
#1st way
plt.plot(x, y)
#2nd way
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, y)
#3rd way
figure = plt.figure()
new_plot = figure.add_subplot(111)
new_plot.plot(x, y)
```

Now my question is -

1. What is the difference between all the three, I mean what is going under the hood when any of the 3 methods are called?
2. Which method should be used when and what are the pros and cons of using any on those?

Comment: I already read that but I didn't find the answer satisfying at all. It explains the hierarchy, but also raises the confusion why isn't there a conventional way, why the figure object even exposed?

Comment: I am not sure if you referred this exact documentation https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html . This answers your question of why figure is even exposed. Personally this is the best explanation of matplotlib I have found. Figure object lets you to add your own Artists directly without axes though this is rarely used unless you want to tweak the "patch" of the figure itself etc. Note that figure is the parent container and hosts axes & artists.

Comment: This guide changed my life, particularly the diagrams. Understanding matplotlib from the name of the methods/classes is murder. Python's laissez-faire treatment of types helps not one bit. https://www.skytowner.com/explore/getting_started_with_matplotlib

Comment: See [Matplotlib Application Interfaces (APIs)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html) - covers _The explicit `Axes` interface_ and _The implicit `pyplot` interface_ and recommends [Why be explicit?](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

This lets you plot just one figure with (x,y) coordinates. If you just want to get one graphic, you can use this way.

**Method 2**

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

This lets you plot one or several figure(s) in the same window. As you write it, you will plot just one figure, but you can make something like this:

```
fig1, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

You will plot 4 figures which are named ax1, ax2, ax3 and ax4 each one but on the same window. This window will be just divided in 4 parts with my example.

**Method 3**

```
fig = plt.figure()
new_plot = fig.add_subplot(111)
new_plot.plot(x, y)
```

I didn't use it, but you can find documentation.

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Method 1 #

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

figure1 = plt.plot(x,y)

# Method 2 #

x1 = np.random.rand(10)
x2 = np.random.rand(10)
x3 = np.random.rand(10)
x4 = np.random.rand(10)
y1 = np.random.rand(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)
y3 = np.random.rand(10)
y4 = np.random.rand(10)

figure2, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax1.plot(x1,y1)
ax2.plot(x2,y2)
ax3.plot(x3,y3)
ax4.plot(x4,y4)

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

**Other example:**

[image]

Comment: @hashcode55 each figure is independent. I will show you an example

Comment: @hashcode55 I will edit with an example (just the figure from my researches in Astrophysics, the script is too long (1300 lines)) ;) Each figure are independent ;)

Comment: I know this is nitpicky, but I'm doing it because `matplotlib` language was confusing to me, and this question shows up when searching about "axes vs. figure in matplotlib." For other noobs, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575451/difference-between-axes-and-axis-in-matplotlib) helped answer that. I think the wording here could be more clear that `subplots()` will return `Axes` objects on a single `figure`.

Answer (score 108):

#### The names of objects

Matplotlib is strongly object oriented and its principal objects are the **figure** and the **axes** (I find the name `axes` a bit misleading, but probably it's just me).

You can think of the **figure** as a *canvas*, of which you typically specify the dimensions and possibly e.g., the background color etc etc.  You use the canvas, the **figure**, essentially in two ways, placing other objects on it (mostly **axes**, but also text labels etc) and saving its contents with `savefig`.

You can think of an **axes** as a sort of Swiss Army knife, a handy object that offers a tool (e.g. `.plot`, `.scatter`, `.hist` etc) for everything, mostly.  You can place one, two, ... many **axes** inside a **figure** using one of many different methods.

#### The `plt` interface

The **plt** procedural interface was originally developed to mimic the MATLAB™ interface but is not really different from the object oriented interface, even if you don't make a direct reference to the main objects (i.e., a **figure** and an **axes**) these objects are automatically instantiated and each **plt** method is, essentially, translated to a call of one of the methods of the underlying fundamental objects: e.g., a `plt.plot()` is a `hidden_axes.plot` and a `plt.savefig` is a `hidden_figure.savefig`.

In every moment you can have an handle on these hidden objects using `plt.gcf` and `plt.gca`, and this is sometimes necessary when one of the object methods has not been ported  to a method in the **plt** namespace.

I'd like to add that the **plt** namespace contains also a number of convenience methods¹ to instantiate, in different ways, **figure** and **axes**.

#### Your examples

> 1st way
>
> ```
> plt.plot(x, y)
> ```

Here you use only the **plt** interface, you can only use a single **axes** in each **figure**, but this is what you want when you are doing an exploration of your data,
a quick recipe that gets the work done...

> 2nd way
>
> ```
> ax = plt.subplot()
> ax.plot(x, y)
> ```

Here you use a convenience method in the **plt** namespace to give a name (and a handle) to your **axes** object, but btw there is also an hidden **figure**.  You can later use the **axes** object to plot, to make an histogram etc, all things that you can do with the **plt** interface, but you can also access all its attributes and modify them with greater freedom.

> 3rd way
>
> ```
> figure = plt.figure()
> new_plot = figure.add_subplot(111)
> new_plot.plot(x, y)
> ```

Here you start instantiating a **figure** using a convenience method in the **plt** namespace and later you use only the object oriented interface.

It is possible to bypass the **plt** convenience method (`matplotlib.figure.Figure`) but you then have to tweak the figure for a better interactive experience (after all, it's a *convenience* method).

#### Personal recommendations

I suggest bare `plt.plot`, `plt.scatter` in the context of an interactive session, possibly using [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) with its [`%matplotlib`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) magic command, and also in the context of an exploratory Jupyter notebook.

On the other hand the object oriented approach, plus a few `plt`
convenience methods¹, is the way to go

- if you have a permanent issue to solve once for all with a
  customized arrangement of finely tuned subplots,
- if you want to embed Matplotlib in the UI of a program you write.

There is a large gray area between these extremes and if you ask me what to do I'd just say *"It depends"*...

---

(1) The convenience methods in the `plt` name space are REALLY CONVENIENT! In particular, when you instantiate Figures and Axes using them, all the minute details needed to deal with interactive windows are automatically taken into account.

Comment: "I find the name axes a bit misleading, but probably it's just me" -- no, it's me as well. Can't be changed though.

Comment: Another thing I just can't understand why people use the `fig, ax = plt.subplot()` idiom when they _don't_ want subplots. In such cases I found the "procedural" style easier. "But probably it's just me... " :-)

Comment: @LaryxDecidua I can see immediately two good reasons ① "Explicit is better than implicit" ② you want to use Figure's or Axes' methods that are not available in the procedural API ­— but possibly there are others…

Comment: Yes, I fully subscribe to 1). Re 2): most of the time the procedural API is enough. At the end of the day I think it boils down to personal preferences -- something one should not argue about :-)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation.  Clears my long accumulated frustration of trying to understand these terms.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: @EBDS You're welcome. And yes, I think this answer is a good one, one of my best.