# Adding minor tick marks to a histogram

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am working through this:
https://medium.com/diogo-menezes-borges/introduction-to-statistics-for-data-science-6c246ed2468d

About 3/4 of the way through there is a histogram, but the author does not supply the code used to generate it.

So I decided to give it a go...

I have everything working, but I would like to add minor ticks to my plot.

X-axis only, spaced 200 units apart (matching the bin width used in my code).

In particular, I would like to add minor ticks in the style from the last example from here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html

I have tried several times but I just can't get that exact 'style' to work on my plot.

Here is my working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

print('NumPy: {}'.format(np.__version__))
print('Pandas: {}'.format(pd.__version__))
print('\033[1;31m' + '--------------' + '\033[0m')  # Bold red

display_settings = {
    'max_columns': 15,
    'max_colwidth': 60,
    'expand_frame_repr': False,  # Wrap to multiple pages
    'max_rows': 50,
    'precision': 6,
    'show_dimensions': False
}
# pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

for op, value in display_settings.items():
    pd.set_option("display.{}".format(op), value)

file = "e:\\python\\pandas\\medium\\sets.csv"
lego = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8")
print(lego.shape, '\n')
print(lego.info(), '\n')
print(lego.head(), '\n')
print(lego.isnull().sum(), '\n')

dfs = [lego]
names = ['lego']


def NaN_percent(_df, column_name):
    # empty_values = row_count - _df[column_name].count()
    empty_values = _df[column_name].isnull().sum()
    return (100.0 * empty_values)/row_count


c = 0
print('Columns with missing values expressed as a percentage.')
for df in dfs:
    print('\033[1;31m' + ' ' + names[c] + '\033[0m')
    row_count = df.shape[0]
    for i in list(df):
        x = NaN_percent(df, i)
        if x > 0:
            print('  ' + i + ': ' + str(x.round(4)) + '%')
    c += 1
    print()

# What is the average number of parts in the sets of legos?
print(lego['num_parts'].mean(), '\n')

# What is the median number of parts in the sets of legos?
print(lego['num_parts'].median(), '\n')

print(lego['num_parts'].max(), '\n')

# Create Bins for Data Ranges
bins = []

for i in range(lego['num_parts'].min(), 6000, 200):
    bins.append(i + 1)

# Use 'right' to determine which bin overlapping values fall into.
cuts = pd.cut(lego['num_parts'], bins=bins, right=False)

# Count values in each bin.
print(cuts.value_counts(), '\n')

plt.hist(lego['num_parts'], color='red', edgecolor='black', bins=bins)
plt.title('Histogram of Number of parts')
plt.xlabel('Bin')
plt.ylabel('Number of values per bin')
plt.axvline(x=162.2624, color='blue')
plt.axvline(x=45.0, color='green', linestyle='--')
# https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html

legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='blue', linewidth=2, linestyle='-'),
                   Line2D([0], [1], color='green', linewidth=2, linestyle='--')
                   ]
labels = ['mean: 162.2624', 'median: 45.0']
plt.legend(legend_elements, labels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance of matplotlib, but for both of those I get: unresolved reference 'ax' when I try to insert either of them into my code.

Comment: Ah...  Those were three separate lines, plus I had to add: ```from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator)```  It's working.  Resubmit as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator()) 
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='r')
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl) to get a better idea about the difference between `plt`, `ax` and `fig`. In broad terms, `plt` refers to the `pyplot` library of `matplotlib`.  `fig` is one "plot" that can consist of one or more subplots. `ax` refers to one subplot and the x and y-axis defined for them, including the measuring units, tick marks, tick labels etc..  Many function in matplotlib are often called as `plt.hist`, but in the underlying code they are drawing on the "current axes". These axes can be obtained via `plt.gca()` or "get current axes". It is not always clear which functions can be called via `plt.` and which only exist via `ax.`. Also, sometimes the get slightly different names. You'll need to look in the documentation or search StackOverflow which form is needed in each specific case.