# How to set the axis of two y axis plots using the same starting point instead of two in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two-axis plots in matplotlib. The two y axis in my plot use different starting point in the graph, How can I correct it so that both the y axis plots use the same axis points.

The code I use to plot is

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax1 =ax.twinx()
#ax.grid(True,axis='both')
#ax.set(xlabel="Voltage", ylabel="Current", title="IV Curve") 
ax.set_xlabel("Voltage [V]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.set_xlabel("Voltage [V]",fontsize = 20)
ax.set_ylabel("Current [I]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.set_ylabel("Power [W]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('red')
ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax1)
#ax.set_title("IV/PV Curve Plot",fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 30, color='blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=20)
plt.ylim (0,10) #adjust the current limits
plt.xlim (0,70) #adjust the voltage limits
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=20)
plt.ylim (0,400) #adjust the power limits
plt.xlim (0,70) #adjust the voltage limits

ax.plot('Voltage', 'Current', data=df, linewidth=4, label='IV curve')
ax1.plot('Voltage', 'Power', data=df, linewidth=4, color='r', label ='PV Curve')
ax.legend( loc='upper right',fontsize=20)
ax1.legend(loc='lower right',fontsize=20)
#pmax and Vmax

Pmax = df["Power"].max()
maxrow = df[df['Power']==Pmax]
Voltage = maxrow['Voltage'].iloc[0]
Current = maxrow['Current'].iloc[0]
xmax1 =(Voltage/70)
xmax2 =(Current/10)
ax.axhline(y=Current, xmin=0, xmax =xmax1,linewidth=4, color ='g',linestyle='--',)
ax.axvline(x=Voltage, ymin=0, ymax =xmax2, linewidth=4, color='g', linestyle='--')

#img = image.imread("/home/hebin/Desktop/PV/Mitsui/Flasher/Mitsui Logo.png")
#plt.figimage(img, 1380, 1150, alpha=1)
plt.margins(0)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig('/home/hebin/Desktop/PV/Mitsui/Flasher/IVC/IV.png')
```

and my output is like this
[image]

In the image you can see the red line and the blue line starts at point zero but at different starting points. I want to correct it and make it start from the same point.

Comment: Some data would be nice for testing.

Comment: You need to change `plt.ylim` to `ax1.set_ylim` etc.. Also, you need to wait with changing the limits until the last command that creates new elements on that ax. Most commands that add new elements also change the limits. Note that `plt.margins()` also change the limits, so you need to choose between either `ax1.set_ylim` or `ax1.margins()`.  Better not use the `plt....` commands that operate on subplots when you have multiple axes.  See e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl

Answer (score 0):

To aling zero in a twin axes, define the following function:

```
def alignZero(ax1, ax2):
    y1Min, y1Max = ax1.get_ylim()
    y2Min, y2Max = ax2.get_ylim()
    ratio1 = -y1Min / (y1Max - y1Min)
    ratio2 = -y2Min / (y2Max - y2Min)
    if ratio2 < ratio1:
        y2newMin = y1Min * y2Max / y1Max
        ax2.set_ylim(y2newMin, y2Max)
    elif ratio2 > ratio1:
        y2newMax = y2Min * y1Max / y1Min
        ax2.set_ylim(y2Min, y2newMax)
```

Then check how it works:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.bar(range(6), (2, -2, 1, 0, 0, 0))
ax2.plot(range(6), (0, 2, 8, -12, 0, 0))
ax1.axhline(0, color='red', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
alignZero(ax1, ax2)
plt.show()
```

The generated picture is:

[image]

In the above example there was a need to set higher max value
for *ax2* (*y2newMax*).

Make the second test changing *-12* in `ax2.plot(...)` to
e.g. *-4*.
This time the **min** value in *ax2* (*y2newMin*) was lowered.

And to see how would the result look like without the above
alignment, make one more test, with commented out invocation
of *alignZero* (zeroes will be now at different levels).