# Is there any equivalent function to xlabel in matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have come across the function set_xlabel in matplot lib and it looks similar to the xlabel function.
Is there any significant difference between those two functions?
If there any, state situations where we can use them?

Comment: xlabel provides you with the label (that is already there on the plot) while set_xlabel sets the label. If there is no label on the plot, sxlabel returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is no difference. But `xlabel` is a method of `pyplot` as you can read from [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html#matplotlib-pyplot-xlabel) and `set_xlabel` must be used when you are using `Axes` [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html).

You can read the difference between using one or another in this thread, for example.
[What is the difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl)