# Why can I not access the 'ax' functions in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a pyplot graph but am unable to access the function family where I change the 'x tick labels'. I know the function exists but my code doesn't want to recognise it. From what I've found on the internet, I might need to move beyond using `plt.plot` but don't really understand why I need to do this.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def grapher(number_of_steps, probabilities):
    '''

    Takes the number of positions and probabilities for these posistions. Plots them
    Positions are on 1D Quantum Walk line and assumed to be a circle (?) eventually, but
    for the loops to be so long as for it to appear as a straight line for our purposes
    '''
    P = 2*(number_of_steps)+1  # Number of Positions

    positions_plot = np.arange(0,P)

    plt.style.use('seaborn-ticks')
    plt.plot(positions_plot, probabilities, marker = 'o', linestyle = "--", label = r"Probability" )
    ticks = np.arange(0,P,P//10) #Location of Ticks
    plt.xticks(ticks)
    plt.xlim(0,P)
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(-N, N+1, P // 10))

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

And this is my error
`File "discretewalk.py", line 134, in grapher ax.set_xticklabels(range(-N, N+1, P // 10)) NameError: name 'ax' is not defined`

Comment: `plt.gca()` instead of `ax` perhaps.

Comment: ax is not something defined in matplotlib, what you seen previously is most likely an axes object: try ax = plt.axes()

Comment: You probably want to read [What is the difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use `set_xticklabels`  on your Axes

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
...
ax.plot(positions_plot, probabilities, marker = 'o', linestyle = "--", label = r"Probability")
...
ax.set_xticklabels(range(-N, N+1, P // 10))
```

or directly set your labels by using [plt.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to go beyond just using `plt`, as pointed out by Johan C. For those folllowing in my footsteps, you have to change the other bits of code as well. ```ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xlim(0,P)
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(-N, N+1, P // 10))

    ax.legend()```