# Plotting two seaborn graphs in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I need to plot two graphs side by side. Here the column in my dataset which I am interested in.

```
X
1
53
12
513
135
125
21
54
1231
```

I did

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
mean = df['X'].mean()
    
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.displot(df, x="X", kind="kde", ax=ax[0]) # 1st plot
plt.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--') # this add just a line on the previous plot, corresponding to the mean of X data
sns.boxplot(y="X", data=df, ax=ax[2]) # 2nd plot
```

but I have this error: `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`, so the use of subplots is wrong.

Comment: The onus is on you to provide dummy data for a [mcve]. And if the first one has index 0, what index does the second axes have?

Comment: I do not think it was essential, but I just added.

Comment: If it's not essential then remove it from your [mcve] ;)

Comment: Thanks JohanC. I am getting three plots, with lines separated from the kde plot.

Comment: Ok, Andras. I had seen also questions with no sample of data and not indication of the type of data, but just code and upvoted. I had provided information on the data I am using. It was randomly generated. It was to understand how to plot one plot with a separate line in a subplot, since it was ok for me to do it with only two plots (separated). By the way, I added the information on data.

Comment: I would like a density plot. The histplot also plots the bars. I would like just a density line, if possible.

Comment: got the error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: yes. It has returned that error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sns.boxplot(..., ax=ax[2])` should use `ax=ax[1]` as there doesn't exist an `ax[2]`.

`sns.displot` is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions), which creates its own figure, and doesn't accept an `ax=` parameter. If only one subplot is needed, it can be replaced by `sns.histplot` or `sns.kdeplot`.

`plt.axvline()` draws on the "current" `ax`. You can use `ax[0].axvline()` to draw on a specific subplot.  See [What is the difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl)

The following code has been tested with Seaborn 0.11.1:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set()
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 53, 12, 513, 135, 125, 21, 54, 1231]})
mean = df['X'].mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="X", ax=ax[0])
ax[0].axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
sns.boxplot(y="X", data=df, ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn kdeplot and boxplot]

Comment: Thanks, JohanC. Unfortunately, as previously mentioned, with my dataset it returns that error. If I plot as distinct charts (kde and box plot), it does not return any error. I cannot understand why I am getting this error. Checking, I think it might be caused by sns.kdeplot

Comment: it works with histplot but not with kdeplot. I have the most updated version, so it is not a problem of version. I am not able to provide more than 10000 of rows ;) (they are all int and I also dropped nan values). It is weird that it is not working only with kdeplot. I also tried as you suggested (with reset_index) but nothing has changed. `sns.kdeplot(data=df.reset_index(drop=True), x="X", ax=ax1)`. Still same error.

Comment: What is the lowest and highest value? How many values are there?  Can you add the image of the plot with `histplot(..., kde=True)` to the post? Could you add a large sample of your data to the post, preferably one that has the same error? Could you try `sns.kdeplot(x=df["X"].to_numpy(dtype=float), ax=ax[0])`?  This looks like a genuine bug, so it is important to get a preferably simple example at seaborn's github.

Comment: I tried with your last suggestion (`sns.kdeplot(x=df["X"].to_numpy(dtype=float), ax=ax[0])`) and it works! No errors, no warnings :) If you could also include in your answer this last piece of code as alternative, it would be great. thank you so much, JohanC

Comment: I'm really interested in knowing what the problem with your dataframe might be.  This is a very unusual and mysterious error. Converting the dataframe to numpy should never be needed, but can help to pinpoint the real error.  Does it work with `sns.kdeplot(x=df["X"], ax=ax[0])`? And `sns.kdeplot(x=df["X"].to_numpy(), ax=ax[0])` without the `dtype`? Can you print out `pd.__version__` to be sure its `1.2.3`? And `sns.__version__` as `0.11.1`?

Comment: it only worked with `sns.kdeplot(x=df["X"].to_numpy(dtype=float), ax=ax[0])`, not with `sns.kdeplot(x=df["X"], ax=ax[0])`. I can confirm that both versions are the most updated (pandas 1.2.3 and sns 0.11.1) as I had to install both recently.