# Adding a line to a barplot in Seaborn pads the graph, how do I get rid of the new margins?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn barplot with a line graphed on top of it that looks like this:

[image: current output]

As you can see, there are thick margins on the plot that appear after adding the line. The plot looks normal if the line is not added:

[image: output without line added]

`plt.margins()` does not work and basically destroys the entire graph. Not sure why. I have not tried additional rc-settings in `sns.set()` because I cannot find the page that lists all the options anymore, so if someone could link that as well so I could bookmark it that would be appreciated.

The barplot is created with:

```py
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (50, 10), 'axes.labelsize': 25, 'ytick.labelsize': 17, 'axes.labelpad': 15, 'legend.fontsize': 20})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
g = sns.barplot(x='City/Town', y="Value", hue="Metric", data=df, ax=ax1)
g.set_title(title, fontsize=30)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

and the line is added with:

```py
ax1.plot(range(len(X)), df.Y_pred[df['Metric'] == bar1]*scale, color='red')
```

where X and Y are numpy ndArrays and scale is just an int.

Comment: @JohanC This did not work. I have `fig.autofmt_xdate()` because it fixes the x-axis spacing. Without it many of the x-labels overlap and become unreadable (not a huge problem on this graph as they are barely readable anyways, but the graph is interactable and can show many fewer entries if the user desires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt to reproduce your plot, although I don't have access to your data, nor the way `X` is determined.

What seems to happen, is that `sns.barplot()` explicitly sets the limits for the x-axis to have nice margins.  `ax1.plot()` resets the margins, using matplotlib's defaults (typically `0.05` or `5%` of the width). So, a solution is to explicitly set very small margins: `ax1.margins(x=0.01)` (or even smaller, depending on your data).

The code below also uses seaborn's `lineplot` to get more consistency in how the x-axis is treated (but `lineplot` also employs matplotlib's margins, so it isn't a solution for this padding).  `autofmt_xdate()` could be replaced by explicitly rotating the labels, which would give some more control about the exact rotation (but this also doesn't influence the padding problem).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'City/Town': np.random.choice([*'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'], 500),
                   'Metric': np.random.choice(['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'], 500),
                   'Value': np.random.randint(10, 20, 500)})
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (12, 6), 'axes.labelsize': 25, 'ytick.labelsize': 17, 'axes.labelpad': 15,
            'legend.fontsize': 20})
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x='City/Town', y="Value", hue="Metric", data=df, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('title', fontsize=30)
df1 = df[df['Metric'] == 'bar1']
sns.lineplot(x=df1['City/Town'], y=df1["Value"]*1.2, ci=None, ax=ax1)
ax1.margins(x=0.01)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn barplot and lineplot]

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I didn't know there was also ax.margins() as well as plt.margins().

Comment: If there is only one subplot (note that `twinx` also creates a subplot, but on the same spot), there wouldn't be a difference. `plt` operates on the "current" subplot, which is usually the last created one. (If you'd create a minimal reproducible example, things would be clear from the start).  Also see [What is the difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl)

Answer (score 0):

I use subplots with a lineplot on top and marplot below. lineplot always has more padding so need to sync them. rcParams does not work for both so have to individually set on the axes:

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.margins(x=0.02)
```