# Is there a function in python that can easily plot such a subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, subplot

- Ultimate goal is to analyse the data and see if linear regresssion is suitable or not.
- Goal is to get 3 matplot.subplots for each of the 3 cars (BMW, Audi A5, Mercedes Benz)
- I tried writing a code, but couldn't get it working:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  
# plot.subplot(nrows, ncols, index of figure, **kwargs)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
x = df1.Age(yrs)
y = df1[['']]
plt.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'Age(yrs)', y  = 'Sell Price($)', color = "black")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'Age(yrs)', y = 'Mileage', color = "green")

plt.show()

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.title("BMW X5")
plt.plot(x,y, color = "black")

# plot 2:
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.title("Audi A5")
plt.plot(x, y, color = "green")

# plot 3:
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.title("Mercedez Benz C class")
plt.plot(x, y, color = 'red')

plt.show()
```

| Car Model | Mileage | Sell Price($) | Age(yrs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW X5 | 69000 | 18000 | 6 |
| BMW X5 | 35000 | 34000 | 3 |
| BMW X5 | 57000 | 26100 | 5 |
| BMW X5 | 22500 | 40000 | 2 |
| BMW X5 | 46000 | 31500 | 4 |
| Audi A5 | 59000 | 29400 | 5 |
| Audi A5 | 52000 | 32000 | 5 |
| Audi A5 | 72000 | 19300 | 6 |
| Audi A5 | 91000 | 12000 | 8 |
| Mercedez Benz C class | 67000 | 22000 | 6 |
| Mercedez Benz C class | 83000 | 20000 | 7 |
| Mercedez Benz C class | 79000 | 21000 | 7 |
| Mercedez Benz C class | 59000 | 33000 | 5 |

Comment: Maybe seaborns `sns.regplot(data=df1, x='Age(yrs)', y='Sell Price($)')`? [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)

Comment: seaborn does not allow subplots. So that is out of the question.

Comment: Seaborn allows a lot of subplots. You need to create the axes via matplotlib. If you use `plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)`, seaborn will draw on the latest created subplot.  You can also give the subplot a name, usually this is a variant of `ax`, e.g. `ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)` and afterwards use `sns.regplot(data=df1, x=..., y=..., ax=ax1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seaborn's [`regplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) can be used to create such a plot. Here is some example code.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''"Car Model"   Mileage "Sell Price($)" Age(yrs)
"BMW X5"    69000   18000   6
"BMW X5"    35000   34000   3
"BMW X5"    57000   26100   5
"BMW X5"    22500   40000   2
"BMW X5"    46000   31500   4
"Audi A5"   59000   29400   5
"Audi A5"   52000   32000   5
"Audi A5"   72000   19300   6
"Audi A5"   91000   12000   8
"Mercedez Benz C class" 67000   22000   6
"Mercedez Benz C class" 83000   20000   7
"Mercedez Benz C class" 79000   21000   7
"Mercedez Benz C class" 59000   33000   5'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 10))

sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == "BMW X5"], x='Age(yrs)', y='Sell Price($)', ax=axs[0, 0])
sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == "BMW X5"], x='Age(yrs)', y='Mileage', ax=axs[0, 1])
axs[0, 0].set_title("BWM X5")
axs[0, 1].set_title("BWM X5")

sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == "Audi A5"], x='Age(yrs)', y='Sell Price($)', ax=axs[1, 0])
sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == "Audi A5"], x='Age(yrs)', y='Mileage', ax=axs[1, 1])
axs[1, 0].set_title("Audi A5")
axs[1, 1].set_title("Audi A5")

sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == "Mercedez Benz C class"], x='Age(yrs)', y='Sell Price($)', ax=axs[2, 0])
sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == "Mercedez Benz C class"], x='Age(yrs)', y='Mileage', ax=axs[2, 1])
axs[2, 0].set_title("Mercedez Benz C class")
axs[2, 1].set_title("Mercedez Benz C class")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: grid of sns.regplot]

PS: You might want to read about the difference between `plt.subplots()` and `plt.subplot()` (with and without final `s`). For example: [What is the difference between drawing plots using plot, axes or figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl).

Via extra variables and `for` loops, fewer lines need to repeated. For example, the same code could be written as:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 10))
car_models = df["Car Model"].unique()
for ax_row, car_model in zip(axs, car_models):
    for ax, y_column in zip(ax_row, ['Sell Price($)', 'Mileage']):
        sns.regplot(data=df[df["Car Model"] == car_model], x='Age(yrs)', y=y_column, ax=ax)
        ax.set_title(car_model)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Seaborn also allows to create the full set of subplots in one go, using [`sns.relplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html). For this to work, the two y-columns need to be "melted" to create a ["long form" dataframe](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Comment: Thank you! I was under such a wrong impression about seaborn. I'm sorry for not having explored the seaborn library and commentign about it. I'm new to this field. Thank you so much. This answers my question.