# xlim and ylim are not setting the limits and the aspect is not equal

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the simple python code below that rotates an ellipse. I want to plot with x and y axes the same range (from -3 to +3) to visually check the rotation is as expected. This works for the x axis, but not so for the y axis (see image below). What am I doing wrong?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)

a = 1
b = 2

xpos = a*np.cos(theta)
ypos = b*np.sin(theta)

rotn = math.radians(45);

new_xpos = xpos*np.cos(rotn)+ypos*np.sin(rotn)
new_ypos = -xpos*np.sin(rotn)+ypos*np.cos(rotn)

plt.plot(xpos,ypos, 'b')
plt.plot(new_xpos,new_ypos, 'r')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim=([-3, 3])
plt.ylim=([-3, 3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems within this code:

1.

```
plt.xlim=([-3, 3])
plt.ylim=([-3, 3])
```

needs to be

```
plt.xlim([-3, 3])
plt.ylim([-3, 3])
```

2. 

The line `plt.axis('equal')` prevents the  `xlim/ylim` settings. You have to remove that line from your code in order to make `xlim/ylim`  work.

> **plt.axis('equal')**
>
> Set equal scaling (i.e., make circles circular) by changing the axis
> limits. This is the same as ax.set_aspect('equal',
> adjustable='datalim'). *Explicit data limits may not be respected in
> this case.*
> https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html

Comment: `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box'` together with `ax.set_xlim(-3,3)` and `ax.set_ylim(-3,3)` would take care of a square subplot.

Comment: @JohanC, how do I get hold of ax? I am a newby to Matplotlib...

Comment: To get the *current ax* you can use `ax = plt.gca()`.  See also [difference between ax and plt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change:

```
plt.xlim=([-3, 3])
plt.ylim=([-3, 3])
```

to instead be:

```
plt.xlim([-3, 3])
plt.ylim([-3, 3])
```