# How can add a new y tick at the right side?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Draw a simple graph and a red horizontal line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([2,3,4,5])
plt.axhline(y = 3.5, color = 'r') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to add a new y tick at the right side for the new red horizontal line,how to make it as below?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [secondary y-axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_yaxis) to position and show the tick at the right.
A secondary axis differs from a ["twin axis"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html): the secondary axis stays nicely aligned with the main axis, while a twin axis is meant to add plot elements with an independent scale.

The example code below changes the "plt" interface for the ["object-oriented"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970424/what-is-the-difference-between-drawing-plots-using-plot-axes-or-figure-in-matpl) interface, which is more appropriate for complex plots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([2, 3, 4, 5])
y_special = 3.5
ax.axhline(y=y_special, color='r')
sec_ax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
sec_ax.set_yticks([y_special], ["1.0"])
plt.show()
```

[image: secondary y-axis with special tick]