# Matplotlib subplots vs axes vs axis (singular / plural)

Tags: matplotlib

Can you please clarify some Matplotlib terminology:

- is the word "subplots" (or "subplot"?) synonymous to "axes"?
- what are singulars / plurals of "axes" and "axis"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is indeed a confusing matter.

In English language the singular is axis and the plural is axes. Two of the kind axis form two axes.

In matplotlib, a `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes` object is often simply called "axes". This object incorporates an xaxis and a yaxis, thus the name. But speaking of that object, one would call it axes in singular. Several of those are still called axes.

**Every subplot is an `Axes` object, but there are `Axes` objects, which are no `AxesSubplot` object.** E.g. an axes, which is created through the subplot mechanism is a `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. This class derives from `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes`, thus this subplot is an axes. You can however also create axes via different mechanisms, e.g. by adding an axes to the figure, `fig.add_axes()`. This would then not be a subplot, but an axes,  `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

print(ax)         # Axes(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
print(type(ax))   # <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>

ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.8,0.1,0.05,0.8])

print(ax2)       # Axes(0.8,0.1;0.05x0.8)
print(type(ax2)) # <class 'matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes'>
```

There are also other axes, like e.g. inset axes, 
`mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes.AxesHostAxes`. This object would also be called axes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 0.2, loc=3) 

print(axins)       # Axes(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)     
print(type(axins)) # <class 'mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes.AxesHostAxes'>
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the thoughts behind the name “axes”? According to the figure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33263181), axes seems to stand something like a drawing area or a floating canvas rather than just the x and y axes. I’m wonder why this object is named “axes” if it really means a drawing area. Thanks!

Comment: @xslittlegrass The "axes" in matplotlib is really the `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes` object, which incorporates the xaxis, yaxis, their labels, ticks etc. The canvas is everything; it can host one figure and a figure can host several axes. We don't speak about drawing area because you can draw everywhere, also outside of the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, its a great answer. However do you think the emphasized line could be better understood if written as **Every `subplot` object is an `axes` object, but there are `axes` objects, which are not `subplot` objects**.

Comment: What's the difference between `Axes` and `AxesSubplot`? If subplot is an instance of `AxesSubplot`. What does an instance `Axes` represent?

Answer (score 4):

Axes is the plural of axis. A subplot usually has an ***x*-axis** and a ***y*-axis**, which together form the **two axes** of the subplot.

Let's talk in terms of function/class names:

`Figure.add_subplot` or `pyplot.subplot` return a `AxesSubplot` object. This in turn contains a `XAxis` and a `YAxis` object.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = ax.xaxis

print(type(ax))   # matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
print(type(x))    # matplotlib.axis.XAxis
```

`XAxis` is derived from base class `Axis`.
`AxesSubplot` is derived from `SubplotBase` and `Axes`.

Answer (score 4):

Axes is just the plural form of axis. For example, x-axis and y-axis together can be called 2 axes or just axes. Subplots contain axes, for the most part. And a figure contains many subplots.

```
                      Figure
                        |
                        v
                ------------------
                |                |
                v                v
             Subplot1         Subplot2
                |                |
                v                v
               Axes             Axes
                |                |
                v                v
            ---------        -----------
            |       |        |         |
            v       v        v         v
          Axis1   Axis2    Axis1     Axis2
```