# matplotlib figure vs subplot vs axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Though I've been able to create basic plots with `matplotlib.pyplot` before, I cannot fully understand what the difference between these are:

- figure
- subplot
- axes
- (axis?)

As I understand, all three of these are objects for the area in which a graph is drawn, so what distinguishes them in terms of what can be drawn inside them?

Comment: Relevant here: [What are the differences between add_axes and add_subplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326680/what-are-the-differences-between-add-axes-and-add-subplot) and [Matplotlib subplots vs axes vs axis (singular / plural)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048255/matplotlib-subplots-vs-axes-vs-axis-singular-plural).

Answer (score 5):

Matplotlib's user guide gives a great description about the [parts of a figure.](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure)

Answer (score 0):

The components are hierarchical:

Figure object: the whole figure

Axes object: belongs to a Figure object and is the space where we add the data to visualize

Axis object: belongs to an Axes object. Axis object can be categorized as XAxis or YAxis.

For further info, visit this link:

[Getting Started with Matplotlib](https://www.skytowner.com/explore/getting_started_with_matplotlib)