# Matplotlib axis for FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, axes, facet-grid

Why
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

does not have `ax` argument that accepts matplotlib axis like other graphs

e.g., https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html?

As I need to set the matplotlib axis for FacetGrid to bring in customized style.

Answer (score 3):

FaceGrid makes the grid, so you cannot pass a grid to it. The individual plots are stored inside, and can be manipulated like in the code below. Also note that that [Axes and Axis are different in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575451/difference-between-axes-and-axis-in-matplotlib). The code below shows a way to obtain both Axes and Axis:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

#dummy data
data= pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.random.randint(0,2, 100),
                         'b':np.random.rand(100),
                         'c':np.random.rand(100)})

# make facetgrid and store in variable
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='a') # make facetgrid with 2 columns, because there are two distinct values in column a of data
g.map(plt.scatter, 'b', 'c') # map function to grid

# the individual axes of the grid are stored in g.
# you can access and edit them like so:

for ax in g.axes[0]:
    ax.set_ylabel('test')
    ax.set_ylim(0,1.5)
    ax.set_title('title')
    # now you can obtain the axis from one of the axes
    x_axis = ax.get_xaxis()
```

[image]