# How can the following: "axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(f))" work since yaxis should be an attribute of AXIS and not of AXES objects?

Tags: python, object, properties, axis, code-documentation

Practicing on visualization as a Python newbie I have encountered this conceptual issue that got me thinking,
Infact I managed to change the price format on the y axis of a boxplot , from scientific notation to something more clear. Here the outputs before and after the formatting of the y axis
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC2cc.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYB60.png)

```
boxy=sns.boxplot(x="waterfront", y="price", data=df)

# my experiments success
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
f = lambda x, pos: f'{x:.0f}'
boxy.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(f))
```

the problem is that I realized that the attribute yaxis should refer to an AXIS object, meanwhile here what i call 'boxy' is an AXES object (at least from the seaborn documentation)

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

You're right saying that seaborn boxplot returns a matplotlib Axes object. And referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575451/difference-between-axes-and-axis-in-matplotlib) answer, we see Axes and Axis objects are different.

Code inspection isn't needed... but under the hood, seaborn uses matplotlib, it is noted in the GitHub [here](https://github.com/seaborn/seaborn/blob/d1c04f2c2c4dbd11ede016405b5ea51380e37f51/seaborn/categorical.py#L757) for boxplots.

when you call `sns.boxplot` part of drawing your plot creates Axis objects... which are objects of the matplotlib.axis module.

The y axis is in fact the first part of `boxy.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(f))`
it is accessed with `boxy.yaxis`. On which you are calling the function `.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(f))`.

To see this, `yaxis = boxy.get_yaxis()` will return the yaxis of the boxy axes object.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:
Again you're correct in the comment that this is not documented from what I could find... but if we look in the matplotlib GitHub [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/710fce3df95e22701bd68bf6af2c8adbc9d67a79/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L2275), we see in the YAxis class declaration:

```
class YAxis(Axis):
    __name__ = 'yaxis'
```

It is just 'YAxis' renamed. Classes will assume their name in the declarative line, unless you re-specify using `__name__` which was done here!

It exists!!!

boxy's yaxis inherets the [`set_major_formatter`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/710fce3df95e22701bd68bf6af2c8adbc9d67a79/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L1567) method from its base class, the ['Axis' class](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/710fce3df95e22701bd68bf6af2c8adbc9d67a79/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L602). Just to confirm this hierarchy try looking with method resolution order:

`print(type(boxy.get_yaxis()).__mro__)`

Should display:

```
(<class 'matplotlib.axis.YAxis'>, <class 'matplotlib.axis.Axis'>, <class 'matplotlib.artist.Artist'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: Hi, The very aspects that you reported created the confusion on this topic to me. What I don't understand is that `boxy.yaxis` it's not ruled by any documentation on matplotlit because it is the same construction as: `matplotlib.axes.yaxis ` that doesn't exist, I couldn't find it on the documentation. Should we infere that `sns.boxplot` returns something that is treated like an AXIS object instead? (In fact matplotlib.axis.yaxis is a fair method/property). To repeat myself: How yaxis is even accessed when i call `boxy.yaxis`? this property shouldn't exist relatively to axes object

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the clarification in your comment. One line about this naming would be nice on the matplotlib docs part!